# Does it make sense to include a predictor that is by definition related to the response variable in a regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

I want to use a multiple logistic regression to model the relationship between two experimental groups (test and control) and accuracy of a procedure, controlling for the experience (in years) of the participants.

```
outcome ~ group + experience
```

The design I am using is paired in the sense that every participant is tested twice, so there are no differences in baseline characteristics between groups (since they are the same individuals). If I was only testing for differences in time, a paired t-test would suffice, but I need to control for experience, hence a regression model is being built.

Time is measured in seconds until the procedure is completed, and accuracy is defined as completing it within a pre-specified threshold (the outcome is 1 if less than or equal to 6 minutes and 0 otherwise). It is expected that time and experience are negatively correlated or, experience practitioners are expected to take less time to complete the procedure.

I would like to test for interactions in this model, but I don't think it makes much sense to interact the group with experience.

```
outcome ~ group * experience
```

I am considering including time in the model and test for interaction with experience.

```
outcome ~ group + experience*time
```

Since time is used in the definition of the response of the logistic model I expect it to be significant even with a small sample size. However it seems to me that including time in this model would be circular reasoning.

```
outcome ~ group*time + experience
```

**Q1:** Is this a correct interpretation?

**Q2:** If I try interactions between time and the group instead, would that tell me that time is modifying the effect attributed to the group?

**Q3:** Does it make sense to test for interactions between experience and group in this setting?

EDIT: I understand Douglas Altman's point of that, while unnecessary dichotomization of a continuous variable is prevalent in medical research, it leads to loss of estimate precision (at the very least). I was able to make the case for a linear model of `time ~ group + experience` for this experiment as a secondary endpoint, but the main goal needs to remain being accuracy, which is why the outcome is a dichotomization of time. This practice is prevalent for a reason :)

Comment: Could you include the formula/specification for the different models you are considering?

Comment: @mkt Sure, I added all of them.

Comment: Can you explain `time` and `outcome` in a little more detail? Also, the question in your title is perhaps too much of an oversimplification. It can be very useful to include predictors that are known to be related to the response variable in some situations, and less so in others, depending on the causal pathways.

Comment: @mkt Time is measured in seconds, and the outcome is 1 if less than or equal to 6 minutes and 0 otherwise. Is that sufficient?

Comment: It seems to me that you could just model time then - what's the reason for taking the continuous value and turn it into a binary? It throws away information.

Comment: But I agree that if `outcome` is defined completely by `time`, it doesn't make sense to use time as a predictor for outcome (or vice versa, for that matter).

Comment: @mkt Time will be assessed as a secondary outcome (with a linear model), but the main goal is to assess accuracy. Thank you for your response, would you expand on it for an answer?

Comment: With an interaction, coefficients reported by a model `summary()` [depend on predictor coding](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/417159/28500). For evaluating a predictor, use a measure that includes _all_ terms involving it. The `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) does that in a way that (unlike the basic `anova()` function) doesn't depend on the order of entry of variables in the model. Use post-modeling tools like those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to illustrate specific scenarios properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`outcome` in this situation is fully determined by `time`. Another way to say this is that it is simply a re-expression of `time` on a binary scale. So if you were to model `outcome` and use `time` as a predictor, the other predictors would not matter - all the variation in `outcome` would be fully explained by `time`.

Actually, that's an oversimplification - it would be worse than this. You would presumably be using a logistic regression, and would encounter the problem of [perfect separation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254266/121522).

I would add that `outcome` does not seem very useful to use as a response variable. You could just model `time` as a response; taking a continuous value and turn it into a binary throws away useful information. It's very unlikely that the binary `outcome` variable is a better metric of 'accuracy' than `time`.

EDIT:

Yes, including `group*experience` makes sense. As EdM says, it would tell you whether the effect of the treatment (`group`) on the `outcome` changes with `experience`. This is easier to understand if you plot the model output.

Also, if you've measured each participant more than once, you will need to model the non-independence of data points. A mixed model (random intercept and perhaps random slope for participant) would help address this.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful. What about the consideration of `group*experience` interaction? Does it help explain anything? How would you interpret this, if it turns out to be significant?

Comment: No, experience is measured in years, as stated. How many years does the participant have performed the procedure for?

Comment: @philsf if the effect of the experimental `group` might differ as a function of prior `experience` in years, then that calls for an interaction between them. The additive model without the interaction assumes no difference in experimental effects as a function of prior experience. I agree with this answer: you would be much better off modeling the time to completion as continuous rather than all-or-none. If you cease all trials at 6 minutes you would code 6-minute trial durations as right-censored and use a "tobit" type of continuous regression.

Comment: The design I am using is paired in the sense that every participant is tested twice, so there are no differences in baseline characteristics between groups (since they are the same individuals).

If I was only testing for differences in time, a paired t-test would suffice, but I need to control for experience, hence a regression model is being built.

Does the interaction between experience and group explain anything in this setting?

Comment: @EdM If I understand your comment correctly, I could formulate a hypothesis that inexperienced participants are more likely to have a different average time (or accuracy) than experts, and test it with the interaction I proposed. Is this a correct interpretation of your comment?

Comment: @philsf not quite. The interaction would examine whether the _effect of the experimental manipulation_ differed as a function of prior experience. The simple additive model would handle "inexperienced participants ... more likely to have a different average time (or accuracy) than experts" on its own, if the effect of the experimental manipulation doesn't depend on prior experience. If you have a large enough data set, it makes sense to include an interaction to check that. Also consider whether your simple linear model of `experience` is reasonable; a flexible spline fit is often better.

Comment: @EdM thanks for your +1 comment. I will add a note to the question acknowledging that a linear model will be preferable to a logistic model for this data. Unfortunately we are not always make all design decisions.

Comment: @EdM would you mind expanding on this point for the interaction as an answer addressing Q3? I am still trying to wrap my head around whether it makes sense to consider this interaction.

Comment: @philsf I've updated my answer to address that. I agree with all EdM's comments.

Comment: @philsf the addition to this answer says what I would have said: there's no downside to including the interaction. For further study, [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/274825/28500) and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/422401/28500) show plots of situations in which an interaction term between a categorical predictor (`group` here) and a continuous predictor (`experience` here) would be important. Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) is a useful resource on choosing predictors and flexible modeling of continuous predictors.